# node.js libxml can NOT install

Tags: node.js, libxml2, cloud9-ide

Try to use `npm install libxml` and an error : Failed at the libxml@0.0.5 preinstall script.

I see another error above : 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
collect2: return code 1
Waf: Leaving directory `/var/www/cloude9node/node_modules/libxml/support/o3/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx_link sh_node_1.o,sh_node_libs_1.o -> o3.node}
  File "/usr/local/bin/node-waf", line 16, in 
    Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 147, in prepare
    error(str(e))
cp: can not get stat для «build/Release/o3.node»: No such  file or directory

So, please help!.

When start install for libxml I see next :

> libxml@0.0.5 preinstall /var/www/cloude9node/node_modules/libxml
>   ./build.sh

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local

All of this I need for install cloud9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be that you're missing [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

Try the following (this is for Ubuntu):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev.
```